# Playing the Ringtone/Text Tone sounds in Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In Monotouch for iOS how do I play the system sounds that are used for alarms/messages/ringtones?

Basically I want my app to play the "Old Phone" or "Robot" sound at key points. I don't want to include a .wav or .mp3 in my bundle.

Comment: Can I ask why this has been -1?  If I have asked something silly then  I would like to know that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.SystemSound.PlaySystemSound.

Here is an [Apple sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018) of how to play different system sounds.